# Flux through complex surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$$
\begin{split}
F &= \left(x^2, y, \frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right) \\
A &= \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: {x^2\over e^x} + {y^2\over e^{-z}} \le 1 \text{ and } -{\pi\over2} \le z \le  {\pi\over2}\right\}
\end{split}
$$

I'm trying to solve this flux exercise with the usual method, applying the divergence theorem. However I've spent 2 hours trying to find a variable change that makes the domain normal so as to actually calculate the integral. Does anyone have any idea on how to treat $A$? It looks like something you would use elliptical coordinates for but the $e^x$ under $x^2$ really makes it much more difficult to me. Do you have suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what is your integral?

Comment: Perhaps something can be done, though I've no idea what. That domain $\;A\;$ looks hopelessly terrible and uncrackable...

Comment: Have you the answer of this exercise?
Maybe there is a typo in the definition of $A$. What if ${x^2\over e^z} + {y^2\over e^{-z}} \le 1$?

Comment: @Max0815 I haven't written the integral because I wasn't able to normalize the domain

Comment: @RobertZ I have no answer sadly. I'm also starting to think it was a typo and it is actually $e^z$.

Comment: @DonAntonio It gives me your same feeling of uncrackableness.

Comment: FWIW, when $y = z = 0$, the constraint $x^2e^{-x}\leq 1$ includes arbitrarily large real $x$. That is, $A$ is not bounded. <> Conceivably there's a symmetry argument, or an intended symmetry argument. Where does the problem come from, and is there a way you can verify it's stated correctly? <> Apropos of nothing, if you edit, would you consider changing "complex surface" to "complicated surface" or something? "Complex surface" has a well-established meaning in complex algebraic geometry. :)